# Where can i find UAAppReviewManager-iOS.bundle

Tags: ios, uaappreviewmanager

I was studying an application which was using UAAppReviewManager. But when i build the project it says UAAppReviewManager-iOS.bundle not found. Same happened with HokeySDKResource.bundle i downloaded it from another app and it worked but could find the UAARM. Please help..!!

Comment: it is not really clear to me what you are asking. It would be prudent that you provide more information on what you are doing (e.g. what applications you are studying) and what the specific problem is (a paste of the actual error code).

Comment: I'm studying an application named Diabetik. It uses the UAAppReviewManager but when i compile the bundle error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of UAAppReviewManager. It sounds like you are running the project and not the workspace. The workspace has the `UAAppReviewManager-iOS.bundle` checked out via Cocoapods and should be found without having to do anything else. If you have further questions on installation, please consider asking on the UAAppReviewManager [issues page](https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAAppReviewManager/issues)

Comment: hello sir, yes I'm running the project not the workspace.. actually I'm new to iOS so i don't know much of the concepts. What i understood from the error is that the bundle file is missing. Same happened with the HockeySDKResource.bundle in the same project as i mentioned in the question. i found the bundle file on internet pasted it in the path stated by Xcode and it worked. Do i have to do something different for this bundle file. please explain in more detail manner. Thank you!!

Comment: Well, if you want to run the example project, run it from the workspace. If you want to integrate UAAppReviewManager into your own project, use cocoapods to do so or copy the files manually as mentioned in the installation instructions in the readme.